# Proving $\forall n\in \mathbb{N} ( a_{n} > 2)$ for a given sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Could you help me with proving the following?:

Let $a_{n}$ be a sequence such as:
\begin{cases}a_{1}=3\\
a_{n+1}=6\cdot \left( \dfrac{1+a_{n}}{7+a_{n}}\right) \end{cases}

I need to prove that this sequence is monotonically decreasing. So the thing is, when trying to calculate $a_{n+1}-a_{n}$ I get that it's equal to: $$\dfrac{-\left( a_{n}+3\right) \left( a_{n}-2\right) }{7+a_{n}}$$
So basically if I prove that $\forall n\in \mathbb{N} ( a_{n} > 2)$ I'm done.

I proved that $a_{n+1}=6\cdot \left( 1-\dfrac{6}{7+a_{n}}\right)$.

Is there any way to assume  that $\forall n\in \mathbb{N} ( a_{n} > 2)$ from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a_n>2$, then we have
$$a_{n+1}=6\cdot\left(1-\frac{6}{7+a_n}\right)>6\cdot\left(1-\frac69\right)=2$$

Comment: But this is what I want to prove... I want to prove that $\forall n\in \mathbb{N} ( a_{n} > 2)$

Comment: I have shown you the inductive step.

Comment: I don't seem to understand, sir. I do understand that if $a_{n} > 2$ these are the steps :) But the thing is that I want to prove that $a_{n} > 2)$ first

Comment: @Maya And you got the central part of a proof.

Comment: What is $a_1$ then?

Comment: $a_{1} = 3 > 2$

Comment: @Maya: I have shown that if $a_n>2$, then $a_{n+1}>2$. And we know that $a_1>2$. Therefore...

Comment: @Maya  Correct. So, you already have $a_n>2$ for $n=1$.

Comment: Oh jesus. Have missed the point. Just a simple induction. Thanks guys!!!